# Is it possible to add markdown to the OS X Server blog editor?

Tags: macos, osx-server

I recently installed OS X Server and have enabled the wiki/blog functionality.

Is it possible to add markdown to the blog editor?

If not, is there software that integrated with the blog functionality and provides a markdown editor as part of a native OS X application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed [an edition of the server guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1176/en_US/WikiDeployment_v10.6.pdf) and see no markdown support anywhere, so I think you may have to go with another tool that easily exports into other formats.

I'd recommend running with [Markdown Service Tools](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/markdown-service-tools/) to start. It's all you need to stick to markdown on a mac. If you like GUIs like I do, you may also like using [MacDown](http://macdown.uranusjr.com/) to write in markdown and export however you need it. It's a great open-source solution to the problem.